# Adding rows to a Pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, cluster-analysis

So I'm trying to sort a dataframe based on a randomly generated row. The dataframe is listed below. What I am trying to do is randomly pick a row, which I will call the centroid in the data frame and then make it so that the the rows which are less than the data are above it, and the rows which are greater than the centroid are below it. However I am not sure how to do that, I have given the dataframe and data below as well as the function I use to compare rows. I decide if a row is less than or greater by summing up the values in the row, and comparing it to the sum of the centroid.

Is there a good way to do this?

Any advice is appreciated.

```
def compareRows(arr1, arr2):
    arr1 = sum(arr1)
    arr2 = sum(arr2)
    return arr1 > arr2
data = np.array(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/cancer.csv',  header=None))
    data = data.T
    #print(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], dtype=float).T
```

If you need anymore information please let me know

Thank you for reading

Comment: A couple of comments: 1. what is your final goal?  I sense a strong [**XY**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/326787) problem here.  I mean, I can solve the problem with `df.iloc[df.sum(1).argsort()]` and voila, every row is in a position such that every other row that compares higher is below and lower is above that row.  In other words, it's sorted.  2. Are you trying to implement randomized quicksort yourself?  If so, I would **Not** be trying to do it by manipulating the dataframe each and every time.

Comment: I'm trying to pick one row randomly from the dataframe and then have the rest of the rows in the dataframe be either above if they are lower or below if they are higher with respect to that row I picked. For example if I pick say row 5, then the dataframe should be sorted such that all rows less than row 5 are above it, and all rows greater than row 5 are below it. The way I decide this is shown in the function I gave above.

Comment: Then just sort the dataframe like this `df = df.iloc[df.sum(1).argsort()]` and randomly select rows with `df.sample(1)`

Comment: Oh ok I see, thanks, but how would I use df.sample(1) in conjuction with the other statement? Forgive me, I'm rather new to this. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: No problem and no need to ask for forgiveness.  Those of us who answer questions do it because we like to.  No one is forcing me to help you (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Grab one row at random with `pd.DataFrame.sample`

  - *note:* this returns a one row dataframe
- create a temporary dataframe `d` without the random row
- create a boolean series of truth values that determine which other rows are greater than our random row
- subset our temporary dataframe by where not greater than, append our random row, append subset of temporary dataframe where greater than our random row

---

```
sampled = df.sample(1)
d = df.drop(sampled.index)
gt = d.apply(compareRows, 1, arr2=sampled.squeeze())

pd.concat([d[~gt], sampled, d[gt]])
# d[~gt].append(sampled).append(d[gt])
```

Comment: I see that makes sense. How would I use df = df.iloc[df.sum(1).argsort()] with this? Or is that no longer necessary as the other functions are doing the swapping?                                                                                        
Thank you for the help

Comment: Well, if you wanted to do this one time or a few times, then use this answer.  If you wanted to keep doing this until all are sorted, then don't bother with this answer, just find the sum of every row and sort the dataframe accordingly... IE, `df = df.iloc[df.sum(1).argsort()]`

Comment: Oh ok I see now, it makes sense. Thank  you so much for your help!

Comment: Another quick note, would it be possible to do this with more than one point?For example, lets say there is a dataframe with 5 rows, I want to randomly pick several rows, lets say 2 in this case, which I will designate as centroid1 and centroid2, and then sort the dataframe based on these rows. In this case, the rows less than the centroid1 are above it, the rows that are greater than centroid1 but less than centroid2 are in between them, and the rows greater than centroid2 are below centroid2. Would that be possible for 2, 3, 4..n centroids?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.

Comment: Yeah I asked it as a new question, but nobody seemed to know if it was possible, so I was just wondering if you might have an idea. But yeah you're right it is a new question

Comment: The answer is yes.  I know how to do it.  Briefly, I'd use searchsorted.  I have a meeting to run to and can't help now.  I'll try to help later.

Comment: All good, take your time, I'm in no rush! And again thank you for the help!